github pages not loading after deployment
I built a documentation site with MkDocs material- https://github.com/iribama/RockyLinux-docs-clone and pushed it to GitHub. After deployment, the site refused to load.
github-pages deploymentsAll my deployments have been successful. The page still has not loaded. Do I have to add github.io to my username?
I'd like to know the issue so I can fix it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
